# What does n*=-1 mean in Java? Particularly n*=

Tags: java

so I'm supposed to read a code and I don't understand what this notation means. I understand that n+= bla, means n+1= bla. But i can't make out the meaning of n*= -1. Can someone tell me real quick. Also does anyone know WHY this would be used instead of a clearer notation? Whoever wrote the code couldn't have possibly saved more than a few letter when using this...

Comment: `n+=bla` is NOT the same as `n+1=bla`. It is the same as `n = n + bla`

Comment: `n*=-1` is exactly the same thing as `n = -n`.

Comment: @TedHopp Which is the same number of characters. I think your example is clearer.

Comment: i guess i mad a wrong guess. made sense then. but now i know thank you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Um, I count 5 OP's version versus 4 for mine (ignoring white space). Or are you counting something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`n += bla` is equivalent to `n = n + bla`

`n *= -1` is equivalent to `n = n * -1`

There's no *functional* reason to choose one notation over the other, it's just a stylistic preference. Java language (and others as well) is full of equivalent statements:

`n++` is equivalent to `n=n+1`

`n=m=1` is equivalent to `n=1; m=1;`

and many many others

Comment: Note that in Java, the [compound assignment operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) do not allow whitespace between the operator and the `=` sign. Thus, `n += bla` is legal, but `n + = bla` is not.

Comment: Actually, there may be a functional reason to choose the compound operator: the left operand is evaluated only once. This makes a difference if evaluating the left operand has side effects, as in `a[i++] += 3;`. (In my view, however, coders who write such code need to be saved from themselves. Or put out of their misery.)

Comment: There's a difference between `++n` and `n++`. `++n` is an equivalent to `n=n+1`. `n++` isn't. `int m=n++` will _first_ assign `int m=n` and _then_ increase n by 1! So this answer is _almost_ correct. ^^

Comment: never said that n++ and ++n is the same thing

Comment: oh, thank you very much. i did try to research it beforehand, i just didn't have the right keyword for it. thx anyway.

Comment: It's actually the equivalent of [`n = (type-of-n) (n+bla)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2). And `n++` is not technically the equivalent of `n = n + 1` (printing `n = n + 1` gives `1` while printing `n++` gives `0`, assuming `n = 0` initially).

Answer (score 2):

`n*= -1` does same thing as: `n = n* -1`

In Java or C++, there are things like:

> +=, -=, *=, /=, &=, |=

They are all the same in a sense.

That is, do the operation first, then do the assignment.

Comment: More precisely, do operation first, *then do implicit cast*, and then do assignment.

Answer (score 2):

It's the compound assignment operator version of the multiplication operator.

The code `n *= x` is equal to `n = n * x`
So in your case, `n *= -1` would make `n` equal to itself multiplied by -1.

The only difference between using the compound assignment operator and the normal assignment operator with a multiplication expression is of stylistic preference.

You can read about compound assignment operators here: http://java.about.com/od/c/g/compoundassgnment.htm

Answer (score 0):

It means n = n*(-1). Just changing the sign.

Answer (score 0):

`n += bla` is the same as `n = n + bla`

`n *= -1` is the same as `n = n * -1`

All of these operators act the same way : `value math-operator assignment-operator other value` is the same as `value assignment-operator value math-operator other value`